# Keep asking for the keychain login password

Tags: macos, proxy, keychain

In this Mac is keep asking for the login keychain password, and this happens after I've set the proxies for the wifi.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this,

1. Open Keychain application in mac
2. Then Goto login
3. Then Delete (option is available after right-click) that IP address or function that is in double-quotes of the prompt.